# Why screen y coordinate is counted from top to bottom

Tags: screen, coordinates

When we draw graps on mathematics or physics lessons the origin of coordinate system is in bottom left corner and Y coord goes up from bottom.
But whe we try to draw something on screen Y-axis switches it direction and coord system origin moves to top-left corner.
Why is that so?

Comment: Could be related to how CRTs used to scan the screen top-to-bottom left-to-right?

Answer (score 0):

It's a historical thing.

Older CRT monitors fire electrons at the screen in a sweeping motion starting at the top, moving down the screen, sweeping from left to right.  They do a complete sweep of the screen typically 50-60 times a second.

Here's a [link to a web page](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/monitor7.htm) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem with CRT monitors. You can try LCD's instead of CRT monitors.